# Congratulations, we're public!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

It's been a tough pull in some ways.  Many users have devoted much time publicizing, discussing, and working toward what we have before us today:

## A public site!

I just want to say that I am thrilled, as I know many others are.  Also, I want to take a moment to say a thank you to those people who have invested much time in this site during its private beta, especially, @Aurora0001, @Helmar, @SeanHoulihane, @Ghanima, @BenceKaulics, @bravokeyl.  There are also many others, and I want to thank you, too, for your work to make this beta public.

And a word to us all: **It's not over yet.**  That's great!  So let's keep contributing quality material for a better web and a better Internet of Things.

Comment: Furthermore, some questions are starting to appear in the "hot network questions", this is encouraging and giving visibility!